# Which DNS in the world receives chages from propagation?

Tags: dns

When I change my ip number, the change is propagated to many servers in the world, but I assume not to every DNS in the world, so which one?
If my domain is thomas.dk, it is clear that the DNS for domain dk will receive the change.
It is also clear that if someone in India should try to access thomas.dk some DNS'es will eventually store the result in cache. But I doubt that anyone in India try to access thomas.dk, so how can it be that the change is propagated to a DNS in India?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DNS changes are only directly propagated to the authoritative name servers for your domain. Other name servers will query the authoritative servers if they don’t have the record cached, or if the TTL has expired on their cached record, and then cache it for re-use. If no one in India ever uses your domain, then your DNS records will never get to India, but any Indian DNS server can get them if they’re needed.

Comment: That is not 100% correct, because what shows
https://www.whatsmydns.net ? I think there must be many authoritative servers with the same information.

Comment: That’s what the answer says though. The site you linked does what it says: It queries multiple name servers around the globe. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @user2304458: It is 100% correct. All the servers in that website are still just caching resolvers owned by various ISPs, and the website checks what data (if any) they have in their cache – its usage of 'propagation' is misleading.

Comment: (And if they _didn't_ have any data cached... well, after the check, they now do.)